# What would you call someone who creates a problem out of thin air?

Tags: single-word-requests

I will type this out as if I were talking to a person.

My thought of this came about at home with my roommate who is about 50 years old. We hang out and talk, watch YouTube, work, live together. Pretty much everything. Well, he and I were hanging out and talking. I say to him *"Hey, I'm gonna go smoke a cig real quick."* Himself acknowledging that I was leaving the room. No problem, right? As it turned out he kept talking as I was outside. He had thought I was just right in the next room. After that he comes out screaming and cursing. Calling me with all sort of names and all colors of the rainbow. Not letting me speak and saying *"Just shut up you don't give a shit."*

My question, being from a grammatical view point would be: what is a single word for an explosive temper used upon another with a huge notice of short term memory loss?

Comment: Short term memory loss? Did he forget what he was yelling at you for?

Comment: I think "bastard" would be the usual term that comes to mind, though saying that is not apt to defuse the situation.

Comment: Avoid loud and aggressive persons; they are vexations to the spirit. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desiderata

Answer (score 1):

The adjective ***[mercurial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mercurial)*** is sometimes used to describe a person who is prone to swift and unpredictable changes in mood. (M-W)

Answer (score 1):

> Hot-headed

One who angers easily, and quite frankly can create problems at the drop of a hat. There are probably many other similar words/phrases to describe this kind of person, such as:

> He's got a **short fuse**

Answer (score 1):

Out of thin air? Clearly the person is a *problem precipitator*.

Answer (score 1):

So many options, so little time ... here's a few that come to mind:

> **histrionic** (or **histrionical**) *adjective*: **1**. excessively dramatic, insincere, or artificial: histrionic gestures. **2**. dramatic
>
> **histrionic** *noun*: **3**. (plural) melodramatic displays of temperament. See TFD [histrionic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/histrionic)
>
> **disagreeable** *adjective*: not pleasant or enjoyable. "another *disagreeable* thought came to him"
>
> *synonyms*: unpleasant, displeasing, nasty, offensive, off-putting, obnoxious, objectionable, horrible, horrid, dreadful, frightful, abominable, odious, repugnant, repulsive, repellent, revolting, disgusting, foul, vile, nauseating, sickening, unpalatable. see Google [**disagreeable**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=disagreeable+definition&oq=Disagreeable+de&gs_l=serp.1.0.0j0i22i30l7.4777.4922.0.7978.2.2.0.0.0.0.110.217.0j2.2.0.ckct%2Ckcns%3D500%2Ckclt%3Dtrue%2Ckcnopqltq%3Dtrue%2Ckcsb%3Dtrue%2Ckcsu%3Dtrue%2Ckcbr%3Dtrue%2Ckcur%3Dtrue%2Ckcuw%3D20%2Ckcnr%3D100%2Ckcab%3Dtrue%2Ckcetioq%3Dtrue...0...1.1.64.serp..0.2.213.mIv6YQjYKL8)
>
> **insufferable** *adjective*: too extreme to bear; intolerable. "the heat would be *insufferable* by July"
>
> *synonyms*: intolerable, unbearable, unendurable, insupportable, unacceptable, oppressive, overwhelming, overpowering
>
> • having or showing unbearable arrogance or conceit. "an *insufferable* bully"
>   synonyms: conceited, arrogant, boastful, cocky, cocksure, full of oneself, self-important. see Google [insufferable](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sa=X&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&biw=1067&bih=550&q=define+insufferable&ei=TItPVfbPDIKdgwTNsoGwBw&ved=0CDUQ_SowAA)

Though I'm not a psychiatrist (nor do I play one on the Web), another word which can legitimately be applied to the behavior this OP depicts is "**abuse**" (or, **abusive**) and, therefore, out of concern I will conclude with a clinical definition which may or may not be pertinent, from the *Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders* (**DSM-5**):

> **Intermittent Explosive Disorder** (sometimes abbreviated as **IED**) is a behavioral disorder characterized by explosive outbursts of anger, often to the point of rage, that are disproportionate to the situation at hand (i.e., impulsive screaming triggered by relatively inconsequential events). Impulsive aggression is unpremeditated, and is defined by a disproportionate reaction to any provocation, real or perceived. Some individuals have reported affective changes prior to an outburst (e.g., tension, mood changes, energy changes, etc.).see Wikipedia [**Intermittent Explosive Disorder**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermittent_explosive_disorder)

Answer (score 0):

You could say that such a person is "quick-tempered".

> **[Quick-tempered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quick-tempered?q=quick%20tempered)** :  Easily made angry

*Example sentence:*

> Of course, we have fights, but he is genuinely quick-tempered so it's
>   over before it's begun.